# how to add multiple hours in swift 3.x

Tags: ios, swift

I suppose to total the timings to Hours and minutes which are in string.
but couldn't find any solution.

my strings are like [5:45 ,4:25, 3:14]

i want to total in terms of hours and minutes.

Please suggest us how to do that.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Split/parse, convert to a base unit (eg. minutes or DateComponents) perform math, covert back to hours-minutes representation.

Comment: can you please share an example of conversion

Comment: separate the string with : and then calculate minutes from hours and add remaining minute in calculated minutes and the add all minutes and then converted back in time format

Comment: can you please share an example

Comment: You should include your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can:

1. Loop through that array of strings.
2. Use `components` to split each of those into two strings, e.g. "01:45" to "01" and "45":
3. Calculate the `TimeInterval` (the number of seconds) that each of those represent.
4. Sum them (e.g. with `reduce`).

Thus:

```
let intervals = ["01:45", "12:55", "34:22"]
let totalSeconds = intervals.flatMap { string -> TimeInterval? in
    let components = string.components(separatedBy: ":")
    guard components.count == 2, let hours = Int(components[0]), let minutes = Int(components[1]) else { return nil }
    return TimeInterval((hours * 60 + minutes) * 60)
}.reduce(TimeInterval(0), +)
```

That returns the sum of all of those in seconds:

> 176520.0

And, if you want that formatted in HH:MM format:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional

let totalString = formatter.string(from: totalSeconds)
```

Resulting in:

> 49:02

Comment: it's works perfect. thanks for helping me :)

Comment: You could add `components.count == 2` to the guard for more protection against invalid data.

Comment: @MartinR Agreed, that's prudent. And he really should figure out what he wants to do if he encounters bad data, as silently proceeding like the above isn't always prudent, either, but that's up to him. Maybe throw an error or whatever.

Comment: thank you so much guys for your valuable response

Comment: @Rob, amazing answer to this question! I was curious how you would approach subtracting multiple times? For example, I changed `.reduce(TimeInterval(0), -)` by adding a minus to subtract all values. I used `let intervals = ["18:15", "1:00"]` as an example but I'm getting a total of `-19:15`. If this was addition, the result would be `19:15` and correct. Do you have any suggestions?